# How to return to a view page from HandleExceptionAsync()

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller, .net-6.0

I am using a custom exception handler for handling errors.

```
  private async Task HandleExceptionAsync(HttpContext context, Exception exception)
        {
           ---------Codes for writing error to db
           errorResponse.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
           errorResponse.Message = string.Format("Internal Server Error. Please 
           contact Suport team. Tracking id: {0}", newid.ToString());
           context.Response.ContentType = "text/html";
           context.Response.StatusCode =(int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
           context.Response.WriteAsync(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(errorResponse));
         }
```

So if error happens in the home controller, it prints error in a blank page under url localhost/home . I want to return the same error to another controller action Account/Error.
What is the possiblity for it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `redirect`.

```
context.Response.Redirect("/Account/Error");
```

Comment: I want to catch the 500 error in program.cs  and redirect. Is it possible

Comment: use `app.UseExceptionHandler("/RedirectErrorPage");`